# Find the a location in a matrix so that the cost of every one moving to that location is smallest

Tags: algorithm

There is a matrix, m×n. Several groups of people locate at some certain spots. In the following example, there are three groups and the number 4 indicates there are four people in this group. Now we want to find a meeting point in the matrix so that the cost of all groups moving to that point is the minimum. As for how to compute the cost of moving one group to another point, please see the following example.

Group1: (0, 1), 4

Group2: (1, 3), 3

Group3: (2, 0), 5

```
. 4 . .
. . . 3
5 . . .
```

If all of these three groups moving to (1, 1), the cost is:
4*((1-0)+(1-1)) + 5*((2-1)+(1-0))+3*((1-1)+(3-1))

My idea is :

Firstly, this two dimensional problem can be reduced to two one dimensional problem.
In the one dimensional problem, I can prove that the best spot must be one of these groups.
In this way, I can give a O(G^2) algorithm.(G is the number of group).

Use iterator's example for illustration:

{(-100,0,100),(100,0,100),(0,1,1)},(x,y,population)

for x, {(-100,100),(100,100),(0,1)}, 0 is the best.

for y, {(0,100),(0,100),(1,1)}, 0 is the best.

So it's (0, 0)

Is there any better solution for this problem.

Comment: You should post it in: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: This has nothing to do with Mathematica - it's an algorithmic problem...  To the OP: is it required that one of the groups *not* move, i.e. that all of the groups move to the location of one of the initial positions?  Example: {(-100,0,100),(100,0,100),(0,1,1)}, for (X,Y,Population) - optimal meeting point seems to be (0,0).

Comment: YES, one of the group can keep static if it's the optimal location. But there is no requirement that one of the groups must keep static.

Comment: In your example, {(-100,0,100),(100,0,100),(0,1,1)}, it's (0,0).

Comment: for x, {(-100,100),(100,100),(0,1)}, 0 is the best.

Comment: for y, {(0,100),(0,100),(1,1)}, 0 is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by kilotaras's idea. It seems that there is a O(G) solution for this problem.
Since everyone agree with the two dimensional problem can be reduced to two one dimensional problem. I will not repeat it again. I just focus on how to solve the one dimensional problem 
with O(G).

Suppose, people are standing like this, a[0], a[1], ... a[n-1]. There is a[i] people standing at spot i. There are G spots having people(G <= n). Assuming these G spots are g[1], g[2], ..., g[G], where gi is in [0,...,n-1]. Without losing generality, we can also assume that g[1] < g[2] < ... < g[G].

It's not hard to prove that the optimal spot must come from these G spots. I will pass the
prove here and left it as an exercise if you guys have interest.

Since the above observation, we can just compute the cost of moving to the spot of every group and then chose the minimal one. There is an obvious O(G^2) algorithm to do this.

But using kilotaras's idea, we can do it in O(G)(no sorting).

```
cost[1] = sum((g[i]-g[1])*a[g[i]], i = 2,...,G) // the cost of moving to the 
spot of first group. This step is O(G).

cur_r = sum(a[g[i]], i = 2,...,G) //How many people is on the right side of the 
second group including the second group. This step is O(G).

cur_l = a[g[1]] //How many  people is on the left side of the second group not 
including the second group. 

for i = 2:G       
    gap = g[i] - g[i-1];
    cost[i] = cost[i-1] - cur_r*gap + cur_l*gap;
    if i != G
        cur_r = cur_r - a[g[i]];
        cur_l = cur_l + a[g[i]];
    end
end
```

The minimal of cost[i] is the answer.

Using the example 5 1 0 3 to illustrate the algorithm. 
In this example,

n = 4, G = 3.

g[1] = 0, g[2] = 1, g[3] = 3.

a[0] = 5, a[1] = 1, a[2] = 0, a[3] = 3.

(1) cost[1] = 1*1+3*3 = 10, cur_r = 4, cur_l = 5.

(2) cost[2] = 10 - 4*1 + 5*1 = 11, gap = g[2] - g[1] = 1, cur_r = 4 - a[g[2]] = 3, cur_l = 6.

(3) cost[3] = 11 - 3*2 + 6*2 = 17, gap = g[3] - g[2] = 2.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of noticing that the objective function can be decomposed to give the sum of two one-dimensional problems. The remaining problems look a lot like the weighted median to me (note "solves the following optimization problem in "http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/R.basic/html/weighted.median.html" or consider what happens to the objective function as you move away from the weighted median).

The URL above seems to say the weighted median takes time n log n, which I guess means that you could attain their claim by sorting the data and then doing a linear pass to work out the weighted median. The numbers you have to sort are in the range [0, m] and [0, n] so you could in theory do better if m and n are small, or - of course - if you are given the data pre-sorted.

Come to think of it, I don't see why you shouldn't be able to find the weighted median with a linear time randomized algorithm similar to that used to find the median (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Randomization#find-median) - repeatedly pick a random element, use it to partition the items remaining, and work out which half the weighted median should be in. That gives you expected linear time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved in O(n>m?n:m) time and O(n>m?n:m) space.
We have to find the median of x coordinates and median of all y coordinates in the k points and the answer will be (x_median,y_median);

Assumption is this function takes in the following inputs:

1. total number of points :`int k= 4+3+5 = 12;`
2. An array of coordinates:

   ```
   struct coord_t c[12] = {(0,1),(0,1),(0,1), (0,1), (1,3), (1,3),(1,3),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0)};
   c.int size = n>m ? n:m;
   ```

Let the input of the coordinates be an array of coordinates. coord_t c[k]

```
struct coord_t {
   int x;
   int y;
};

1. My idea is to create an array of size = n>m?n:m; 
2. int array[size] = {0} ; //initialize all the elements in the array to zero

for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
   array[c[i].x] = +1;       
   count++;
}
int tempCount =0;
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
   if(array[i]!=0)
   {
      tempCount += array[i];
   }
   if(tempCount >= count/2)
   {
      break;
    }
}
int x_median = i;

//similarly with y coordinate.

int array[size] = {0} ; //initialize all the elements in the array to zero 
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
   array[c[i].y] = +1;       
   count++;
}
int tempCount =0;
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
   if(array[i]!=0)
   {
      tempCount += array[i];
   }
   if(tempCount >= count/2)
   {
      break;
   }
}

int y_median = i;

coord_t temp;
temp.x = x_median;
temp.y= y_median;
return temp;
```

Sample Working code for MxM matrix with k points:

*Problem
Given a MxM grid . and N people placed in random position on the grid. Find the optimal meeting point of all the people.
*/
/*
Answer:
Find the median of all the x coordiates of the positions of the people.
Find the median of all the y coordinates of the positions of the people.
*/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct coord_struct {
int x;
int y;
}coord_struct;

typedef struct distance {
   int count;
}distance;

coord_struct toFindTheOptimalDistance (int N, int M, coord_struct input[])
{
    coord_struct z ;
    z.x=0;
    z.y=0;
    int i,j;
    distance * array_dist;
    array_dist = (distance*)(malloc(sizeof(distance)*M));
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        array_dist[i].count =0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        array_dist[input[i].x].count +=1;
        printf("%d and %d\n",input[i].x,array_dist[input[i].x].count);
    }
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<=N/2;)
    {
       printf("%d\n",i);
       if(array_dist[j].count !=0)
          i+=array_dist[j].count;


       j++;
    }

   printf("x coordinate = %d",j-1);
   int x= j-1;
   for(i=0;i<M;i++)
       array_dist[i].count =0;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
       array_dist[input[i].y].count +=1;
    }
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<N/2;)
    {

       if(array_dist[j].count !=0)
          i+=array_dist[j].count;

       j++;
    }

    int y =j-1;
    printf("y coordinate = %d",j-1);
    z.x=x;
    z.y =y;
    return z;
}
int main()
{
coord_struct input[5];
 input[0].x =1;
 input[0].y =2;
 input[1].x =1;
 input[1].y =2;
 input[2].x =4;
 input[2].y =1;
 input[3].x = 5;
 input[3].y = 2;
 input[4].x = 5;
 input[4].y = 2;
int size = m>n?m:n;
coord_struct x = toFindTheOptimalDistance(5,size,input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is fine, and divide the problem into two one-dimensional problem. And the time complexity is O(nlogn).

You only need to divide every groups of people into n single people, so every move to left, right, up or down will be 1 for each people. We only need to find where's the (n + 1) / 2th people stand for row and column respectively.

Consider your sample. {(-100,0,100),(100,0,100),(0,1,1)}.

Let's take the line numbers out. It's {(-100,100),(100,100),(0,1)}, and that means 100 people stand at -100, 100 people stand at 100, and 1 people stand at 0.

Sort it by x, and it's {(-100,100),(0,1),(100,100)}. There is 201 people in total, so we only need to set the location at where the 101th people stands. It's 0, and that's for the answer.

The column number is with the same algorithm. {(0,100),(0,100),(1,1)}, and it's sorted. The 101th people is at 0, so the answer for column is also 0.

The answer is (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of O(n) solution for one dimensional problem, which in turn means you can solve original problem in O(n+m+G).

Suppose, people are standing like this, a_0, a_1, ... a_n-1: a_0 people at spot 0, a_1 at spot 1. Then the solution in pseudocode is

```
cur_result = sum(i*a_i, i = 1..n-1)
cur_r = sum(a_i, i = 1..n-1)
cur_l = a_0

for i = 1:n-1
   cur_result = cur_result - cur_r + cur_l
   cur_r = cur_r - a_i
   cur_l = cur_l + a_i
end
```

You need to find point, where cur_result is minimal.
So you need O(n) + O(m) for solving 1d problems + O(G) to build them, meaning total complexity is O(n+m+G).
Alternatively you solve 1d in O(G*log G) (or O(G) if data is sorted) using the same idea. Choose the one from expected number of groups.

Comment: You are assuming the array is sorted. You'll also need O(n*log(n)) to sort the array.

Comment: Initially all a_i = 0. Then we move through all elements in G and do a[q_j.x] += q_j.people. Its O(G)

Comment: I can prove that the optimal point must come from the G groups. Using your idea, It seems that I can give a O(G) algorithm

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this in O(G Log G) time by reducing it to, two one dimensional problems as you mentioned.

And as to how to solve it in one dimension, just sort them and go through them one by one and calculate cost moving to that point. This calculation can be done in O(1) time for each point. 
You can also avoid Log(G) component if your x and y coordinates are small enough for you to use bucket/radix sort.

Comment: I cannot figure out your algorithm. Can you explain your idea more detail?  "sort them" means sort the whole one dimensional problem? Can you explain your idea using the example above? Thanks very much.